# Gmail zend imap - latency when fetching messageids

Tags: email, zend-framework, gmail

I have this code to fetch emails from gmail using imap with the zend framework. I go back two days in my search (as I do not want all messages) all works well but it takes forever to load the messages and I need to do this for 5+ users, it seems like the search goes through the entire gmail message archive in getting the newest ones.

My code looks like this:

```
 $dato = date('j-F-Y', strtotime($Date. ' - 2 days')); 
 $dato = "SINCE ".$dato;
 $messageids = $imap->search(array($dato));
```

Any ideas on how to make zend work faster? would it perhaps be better with only getting the headers - and if so then how do I achieve this?

Will it be able to get back 2 hours or so?

Edit: is there some way of using the search for "UNSEEN SINCE date time-1hour" ? I can only make it work with one whole day.. and that is too long...

```
$dato = "UNSEEN SINCE ".$dato;
```

seems to work, but still it would be better to get it updated once an hour going an hour back instead of updating once an hour going a day back, updating once a day will only cause delay in working with the messages at the office. (from the internal webserver)